# How to use arrays in this java code so I can output values in order they are assigned to positions ?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, formatting

I am a java beginner and I am coding a program that gets the name of the item, units of that item, price/unit and the total price. I am trying to put those values in different arrays
so I can access them later when I create a sort of a receipt but I don't know how to assign those values in array positions and then access those same positions without having to hard-code. A loop is the best option but I dont know how to set this thing up. Help and suggestions would really be appreciated. Keep in mind that I cant do advanced stuff like matrices and 3D arrays. If you can keep it simple it would be awesome.

This is the main class, I have a tester class with main() that runs userInput() and menu() but theres no point in putting that in because its only 2 lines of code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GroceryList {

    // instance variables 
    Scanner Price, Items, NumItems, Units;

    private double myGross, myNet;
    private final double STATETAX;
    private double totalPrice, unitPrice;
    private String itemName;
    private int totalUnits;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////// arrays I will use
    private double[] totalPrice1;
    private double[] unitPrice1;
    private String[] itemName1;
    private int[] totalUnits1;

    public GroceryList()
    {
        STATETAX = 0.06;
        double[] totalPrice = new double[50];
        double[] unitPrice = new double[50];
        String[] itemName = new String[50];
        int[] totalUnits = new int[50];
    }

    public void userInput()
    {
        Scanner Price = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Items = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Units = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner NumItems = new Scanner(System.in);

        int u, c, totalItems;// c is the number of items that has to equal totalItems in order for the loop to break
        double price;
        String item;//gets the name of the item
        c=0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Grocery List ! \n");
        System.out.print("Enter the total number of items you want to buy (not total units !) : ");
        totalItems = NumItems.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        do 
        {
            c++ ;
            System.out.print("Enter the item name : ");
            item = Items.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the units of " + item + " you want to buy : ");
            u = Units.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter the price of a/n " + item + " : $");
            price = Price. nextDouble();

            /*this would make only one value appear at the receipt, which would be only one item name, one unit price, one price/unit, one total price and the other values calculated
   would not appear on the receipt because you cant assign more than 1 value to a variable so thats why I need arrays. 
             */
            itemName = item;
            totalUnits = u;
            unitPrice = price;



            calc(u,price,item);
        }
        while (c < totalItems);
    }

    public void calc(int u, double p, String i)
    {
        double total;//total amount of $ for 1 item
        total = u*p;
        System.out.println("Total price of " + i + " : $" + total + "\n");
        grossPay(total);
        totalPrice = total;
    }


    public void grossPay(double total)
    {
        double gross;
        myGross += total;
    }

    public double tax()
    {
        double temp;
        temp = myGross*STATETAX;
        myNet = myGross - temp;
        return myNet;
    }

    public void menu()
    {

        System.out.printf("%-10s %6s %11s %11s" , "ITEM :" , "UNITS :" , "PRICE :" , "TOTAL :"); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-11s %2d %7s $%4.2f %5s $%2.2f", itemName, totalUnits,"", unitPrice,"", totalPrice);
        System.out.println();



    }

    public void payment()
    {
        System.out.println("Amount before tax : $" + myGross);
        System.out.println("Amount after tax : $" + tax());

    }

}//end GroceryList
```

Comment: Some of your comments are hard to read. Considering separating them into more lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a little restructure ;)

First of all, you really don't need the array `totalPrice1`, the total price is the total price, there's only one...(IMHO)

Instead of initialising the arrays in the constructor, you should initialise them in the `userInput` method, this is when you know how many items the user will want to enter.  Otherwise you will run into problems if I want to enter 51 items ;)

```
System.out.println("Welcome to Grocery List ! \n");
System.out.print("Enter the total number of items you want to buy (not total units !) : ");
totalItems = NumItems.nextInt();
System.out.println();

unitPrice1 = new double[totalItems];
itemName1 = new String[totalItems];
totalUnits1 = new int[totalItems];
```

(nb- You have bug in your original code, in the constructor, you had declared the arrays as local variables, but used the wrong names any way, this would leave the instance fields uninitialised, raising a `NullPointerException`)

While it's certainly not an error, it would simpler to increment `c` at the end of the loop...

```
do {
    //...
    calc(u, price, item);
    c++;
} while (c < totalItems);
```

This will mean you don't need to constantly keep adjusting the position for the arrays.

In you "collection" loop, you need to assign the values the user has entered to each array...

```
do {
    //...
    itemName1[c] = item;
    totalUnits1[c] = u;
    unitPrice1[c] = price;
    //...
} while (c < totalItems);
```

Having said all that, it would actually be easier to use something like a `for-next` loop...

```
for (int c = 0; c < totalItems; c++) {
    //...
}
```

IMHO...

Finally, when you're ready, you can print the receipt by simply looping through the arrays...

```
for (int index = 0; index < totalItems; index++) {
    double itemCost = unitPrice1[index] * totalUnits1[index];
    System.out.println(itemName1[index] + " @ " + unitPrice1[index] + " x " + totalUnits1[index] + " = " + cost);
}
System.out.println("Total Cost: " + totalPrice);
```

### Some feedback ;)

Having said all that, I would, personally, create yourself a simple `Object` which contained all the required information, for example;

```
public class ShoppingItem {
    public String name;
    public double unitPrice;
    public double quantity;
}
```

Then, all you would need is a single array, for example...

```
//private double[] unitPrice1;
//private String[] itemName1;
//private int[] totalUnits1;
private ShopingItem[] items;
```

Then, as required, you would simply create a new instance of this item and fill it out, for example...

```
items[c] = new ShoppingItem();
items[c] = item;
items[c] = u;
items[c] = price;
//itemName1[c] = item;
//totalUnits1[c] = u;
//unitPrice1[c] = price;
```

And printing the receipt would look for like...

```
for (ShoppingItem item : items) {
    double itemCost = item.unitPrice * item.quantity;
    System.out.println(item.name + " @ " + item.unitPrice + " x " + item.quantity + " = " + cost);
}
System.out.println("Total Cost: " + totalPrice);
```

For a more "advanced" output, I would encourage you to take a look a something like [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and/or `System.out.printf`

Take a look at [this example](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for some ideas ;)

Comment: I am using the constructor from another class through an object like GroceryList gc = new GroceryList(); and then gc.userInput(); so I think that would be the bug you were talking about.

Comment: In your constructor, you had created `double[] totalPrice = new double[50]; double[] unitPrice = new double[50]; String[] itemName = new String[50]; int[] totalUnits = new int[50];`.  These are all local to the constructor, meaning that once you exit the constructor, they can no longer be referenced.  Their names don't even match the field instances any way (`private double[] totalPrice1; private double[] unitPrice1; private String[] itemName1; private int[] totalUnits1;`), which would leave these uninitialised (`null`)...

Comment: Yeah basically I really have to reconstruct this thing because its getting out of control. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're moving in a good direction!  You might find [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of some help as well..

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would (wrote this as I misread your meaning of sort):

Create an Object `Item` which has the fields `name`, `totalPrice`, `unitPrice`, `totalUnits`. Then in your grocery list you don't need to have 4 arrays, just one array of `Items`. Saves the dubious task of having to keep track of indices.

If you also create an `ItemComparator` class that implements [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) you can define how they should be sorted and you can then sort your array using

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(itemsList), new ItemComparator());
```

You also don't need four Scanners, you can use the same scanner since they are all on `System.in`

Comment: This would be a good step after you first get used to using arrays, The answer MadProgrammer gave is more appropriate firstly.

Comment: Arrays are fun, `List`s are simpler ;)